# How to run Google Chrome Headless Puppeteer code

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer (specifically to [take a screenshot after a delay](https://superuser.com/questions/1209741/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-page-n-seconds-after-page-is-loaded-with-chrome-he), but my problem is more basic than that)

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

I have run the following commands successfully.

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install node
npm i puppeteer
```

The documentation says the following

> Puppeteer will be familiar to people using other browser testing
>   frameworks. You create an instance of Browser, open pages, and then
>   manipulate them with Puppeteer's API.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with other browser testing frameworks, and I do not know what they mean by "create an instance of Browser".

I see the examples/screenshot.js file. It contains the following.

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://example.com');
await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

await browser.close();

})();
```

I don't see mentioned in any README, documentation, or Q&A on how to run this code. Everything seems to assume that this step is obvious, which it might be but I'm at a loss as I'm not terribly familiar with Node.

- I have called `node examples/screenshot.js`, but the terminal doesn't
  give any feedback and the image isn't created in any path I specify.
  Permissions are correct.
- I tried calling `node install.js` first as well.
- I have tried running the script inline directly in the terminal, but
  that gives "unexpected token (" in terminal.
- I have even tried running it in the browser. Obviously that didn't
  work.

How do I run puppeteer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js version that you have installed via apt are probably rather older/stable.

puppeteer requires the newer node.js (7.6+) that supports async/await functions, here's a simple way to install it at the time of writing: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

You then indeed run the example script by issuing command

```
node examples/screenshot.js
```

and the screenshot should be in the directory from where ytou ran the command.